# Jquery Date picker: Select one date, automatically update second field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery Date Picker plugin by Kelvin Luck ( http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/ ) and need to do the following, maybe somebody can help me:

On a website for travel insurance I have two date fields, one for a start date and one for an end date. There's also a third field (a select) that selects plans, each with a different coverage, in a number of days. The idea would be that if you select a plan for, for example, 15 days, and a start date of X, the second date field would be magically populated with a date of X + 15 days.

Thing is, my JavaScript knowledge is not what you would call advanced.

Anybody has some experience with the plugin, or could at least give me some pointers?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Around here, people like that you have put in some effort.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at several things. Namely the plugin's demo pages, searches on google and StackOverflow, the plugin's docs and such. But so far I haven't found anything that does that. Only some examples where you can define a range for the second input, like in http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerStartEnd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#date2").datepicker();  
    $("#date1").datepicker({  
        onSelect: function(){  
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');  
            $("#date2").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));  
            $("#date2").datepicker("setDate", "+15d");  
        }  
    });  
});
```

I guess this is what you need

Comment: ¿This code uses the UI Datepicker, right? Been looking into solutions with that one for the last hour. Will try this, thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. I am forever grateful. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
onSelect might be what you are looking for, when you select the first date you can add 15 days to it and populate the second field

The datepicker you are using is the old version, I think, you should look into jquery datepicker at the link above

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that one. I'm just using that one because that's what the site i have to modify has. (Obviously I didn't make it)

Answer (score 1):

I modified one of the samples. something like this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#start-date').bind(
        'dpClosed',
        function(e, selectedDates)
        {
            var d = selectedDates[0];
            if (d) {
                d = new Date(d);
                var timeframe = $('.plan-length').val();
                $('#end-date').dpSetStartDate(d.addDays(timeframe).asString());
                $('#end-date').dpSetEndDate( d.addDays(timeframe + 1).asString());
            }
        }
    );      
});
```

where `#start-date` is the start date input, `.plan-length` is a selector that will return the number of days the plan would add (obviously i dont know your implementation, so this would surely have to change). and `#end-date` is the end date input.

**EDIT:** I also highly recommend you look at the jquery UI DatePicker plugin, as it is much more flexible and IMO easier to use.

**EDIT 2:** You could set the start and end date, so it is only one choice.
I added 1 more line to the code above.

Comment: Thanks. This is close, but apparently with this plugin you can only set the start dates and not an exact one. I'll look into the UI plugin.

Comment: You could set the start and end date, so it is only one choice. I added 1 more line to the code above.